# Wifi keeps disconnecting on 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, realtek

Upgraded ubuntu to 13.10, I am using a Realtek wifi card on a minipc.
The wifi connection goes slower than it should: speedtest gives me a 15mB/s download when on my phone it gets around 30 and the connection keeps dropping (signal level goes from 4 to 0 and I am asked wifi passw again and again).

This is the output of

```
lsmod | grep rtl

rtl8192ce             137725  0 
rtlwifi               110108  1 rtl8192ce
mac80211              596969  2 rtlwifi,rtl8192ce
cfg80211              479757  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

If i run iwconfig I get

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"MYNETWORK"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: A4:B1:E9:6C:B0:B3   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=33 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:4   Missed beacon:0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run `uname -r` to give us the kernel version. Do you have ethernet access to download packages? And are you on a 64 or 32 bit install?

Comment: 3.11.0-14-generic


I am on a 64 bit version

Answer (score 1):

There have been a lot of wifi problems with 13.10 with Kernel 3.11. This is often (not always) fixed by upgrading to 3.12. If you have wired internet download the new kernel:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200-generic_3.12.0-031200.201311031935_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200_3.12.0-031200.201311031935_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-saucy/linux-image-3.12.0-031200-generic_3.12.0-031200.201311031935_amd64.deb
```

Then run:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.12.0-*.deb linux-image-3.12.0-*.deb
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

This should install the new kernel and then reboot.

Comment: user1703577 commented that they have tried this and it did not work. (In future please use comment rather than editing post)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to edit the post, I did it by mistake

Comment: No problem, sorry my idea didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Type

`test(hd0) badram(hd0) sleep 10 set net_default_server=(hd0)`,

and

`set pxe_default_Server=hd0`

and restart Ubuntu it should work fine.

Comment: So I should type unetbootin boot usb on my terminal?

Comment: Michaele, When I typed your suggestion I received the message: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `hd0' Any other suggestion?

Comment: Can you please say where to type these commands?

Comment: Typed the first line and got this error



`bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'hd0'`

Comment: Hi. its proplealy other then Hd0